# Kallithea setting up ldap support can't find admin->ldap section on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, python-ldap, kallithea

Hello I'm trying to setting up ldap support for kallithea.
I followed the instructions here:
https://pythonhosted.org/Kallithea/setup.html

In the Setting up LDAP support section it says:
LDAP settings are located in admin->ldap section

I couldn't find the admin->ldap (file?) to configure the ldap setup.

Where do I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the admin->ldap part is in the kallithea service.

To configure ldap you have to go to admin->authentification and enable kallithea.lib.auth_modules.auth_ldap checkbox in kallithea web frontend.